# Docker installation issue on VMware

Tags: docker, installation, debian, raspbian, vmware-workstation

Docker (1.5-1+b1) is installed successfully but not working. I am running it inside of VMware. When I run the command "**sudo docker run hello-world**",
it results "command not found". 
[image]

Comment: Can you show the result of `sudo dpkg -l | grep docker` and `whereis docker`?

Comment: @sergkondr please see the link (http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a3ody.jpg)

Comment: You should to install `docker-ce`: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: @sergkondr I have tried it already but it couldn't go in vain

Comment: Just run this steps:
1. sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
4. curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
5. sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=XXXX] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
6. sudo apt-get update
7. sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
And change XXX to your arch(you can get it here: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep arch=`)

Comment: @sergkondr Look at the attached image , seems like the corrupted file.
(http://oi68.tinypic.com/2v2fexs.jpg)

Comment: According to my previous comment: "And change XXX to your arch"

Comment: Following the last comment about architecture but getting the same result, please have a look [error] (http://oi64.tinypic.com/2mgo110.jpg)